# Using index hint causes MongoTemplate query to take longer

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

A spring Mongo Query (`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query`) is conditionally build based on a users input, for example the user can query based on any combination of timestamp, status or product name. The product name field does not need to be exact (see regex in query below).

**Issue**
When including productName in the query, and hinting the `productName` index, the query takes roughly 50% longer to execute.

**Example data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d076d80bad441ed114419d"),
    "productName" : "Windex",
    "status" : "instock",
    "timeStamp" : 00:00:00 ...
}
```

**Query creation and execution**

```
final List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = new Query().with(pageable);

if (status != null) {
    criteria.add(Criteria.where("status").is(status));
}

if (productName != null) {
    criteria.add(Criteria.where("productName").regex("(?i).*" + productName + ".*"));
    // Using the index hint below results in longer execution times
    //query.withHint("productName_index");
}

List<Product> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
```

**Index**

```
{
    v: 2,
    key: {
        _fts: 'text',
        _ftsx: 1
    },
    name: 'productName_index',
    weights: {
        'productName': 1
    },
    default_language: 'english',
    language_override: 'language',
    textIndexVersion: 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`productName_index`, despite its misleading name, is a compound text index on  `_fts` field and `_ftsx` field. Weights on `productName` doesn't do anything there.

Hinting forces mongo to use this index which doesn't help with regxp query on `productName` field. Because mongo cannot use any other index, it fetches all documents and apply regex filter, which is a bit slower than COLLSCAN.

Usually query planner is pretty good and hinting should be used only when you know exactly why the index chosen by mongo is not ideal.

Comment: I now also see in the IDE that the index is of type compound. In my situation the query is taking ~60 seconds when given a single name like 'windex', would creating a true text index help here?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "true" text index, but you don't use text search in the query, so I don't see how it can possibly help. Now, before we go deeper to the query optimisation topic I'd like to remind the original question was "why hinting a wrong index slows things down".